# I have 4x4 Planes subidivided , i would like to sculpt them all at the same time so the remain connected at the edges

Tags: sculpt

I know i can select multiple thing to sculpt but that still leaves me with disconnected edges. : - )

BUMP

Comment: Hello. I think it's better you sculpt a big grid and subdivide it later into four objects.

Comment: *BUMP* read rules of the site please. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: @LeoNas Thanks, but if it is subdivided say 16 times, thats a lot  of quads and i don't want to count like 50 from each side 16 times...

Comment: What i am doing is a big terrain for game, but i want it separated into "chunks" for occlusion and optimization overall you get the drift...
so there is 1 plane scaled 128x
subdivided 16x 
and this huge plane is in 4x4 Big Chunk,
which is also 4x4. so 256 terrain chunks how would i first sculpt them and then separate...? looking for optimal solution : - ) THANKS :- )

Comment: You can create the plane, subdivide once, select that new edges and use mark seam to know exactly the loop you want. Now you can subdivide it 15x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Bringing the comments to an answer.

Create the plane, enter Edit Mode and subdivide it once.

Select that new edges and use Mark Seam.

Select all and subdivide it at your taste.

After sculpting the terrain, enter Edit Mode again. Change selection mode to Face.

Hit <kbd>L</kbd> over some part so select what you want to separate and separate it.

Image with the process here:

[image]

Comment: Thank You ,Very Elegant.